# Setting a value sent from a link_to a partial in another view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, partial, link-to

So i have this link from a partial in a view:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Inscribir Ejemplares en la Carrera', home_carreras_path(@race, :meeting_id => meeting.id) %></td>
```

That link sends me to another view where two other partials are rendered.

The browser address looks like this:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/home/carreras?meeting_id=6
```

So you see that the value i sent from the link is there, and i want to pass that value, that number to one of the partials rendered in that view.

i haven't found how to do that, i searched a lot before asking. So please i hope someone here can help me. Thank you.

EDIT: ADDING MORE INFO

Controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
   render :layout => 'principal'
  end

  def carreras
   @meeting_id = params[:meeting_id]
   render :layout => 'principal'
  end
end
```

Not much action there :/

The Partial where the hidden field is:

```
<%= form_for(race) do |f| %>

   <ul>
    <% race.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
   </ul>
 </div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.hidden_field :meeting_id %><br />
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :carrera_num %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :carrera_num %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :caballo_num %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :caballo_num %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :caballo_nombre %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :caballo_nombre %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :distancia %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :distancia %>
</div>
<BR>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit "Inscribir Ejemplar" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your controller actions for `carreras`, you can set an instance variable for the meeting_id.

```
def carreras
  @meeting_id = params[:meeting_id]

  # rest of controller action
end
```

`@meeting_id` will then be available to you throughout your rendered action.

You can supply your `hidden_field` tag with an options hash to set the value.

`<%= hidden_field :meeting_id, value: @meeting_id %>`

Comment: I have a hiddend field in the partial rendered in that view that is supposed to get that value. But it doesnt... do i have to pass that value in the render partial code? Something like this maybe: <%= render 'form_race', :race => Race.new(:meeting_id) %>... which doesnt work by the way

Comment: Can you add your controller action and the part of your partial where your hidden field is declared?

Comment: Thank you!!! Cannot believe how simple and logical that was. But well im learning. Thank you for answering!